# Load Data In File works in MySQL Workbench but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

if I run the following sql on MySQL Workbench then everything works fine but as soon as I try to invoke it via PHP:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C://stats/imports/All Members/ALL_MEMBERS_(ACTIVE)_30_09_2018.csv'
INTO TABLE stats.members_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\\\'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(mem_no, @entered_on, @date_of_joining, mem_status, @mem_status_date, pitch_code, branch_code, section_code, sub_section_code, mem_sector, emp_status, employer, homeworker, workplace, personal_contract, pay_method, @date_paid_upto, home_country, work_country, equal_opps_consent, mem_ben_consent, priv_agree_consent, app_method, age, gender)
SET date_of_joining = str_to_date(@date_of_joining,'%d-%b-%Y'), 
entered_on = str_to_date(@entered_on,'%d-%b-%Y'), 
mem_status_date = str_to_date(@mem_status_date,'%d-%b-%Y'), 
date_paid_upto = str_to_date(@date_paid_upto,'%d-%b-%Y')
```

... I get an error message stating:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''
>                       (mem_no, @entered_on, @date_of_joining, mem_status, @mem_s' at line 6

The web application, database and csv file are all on the same server.

The PHP code is:

```
function loadData() {


    try
    {
        $db = DAO::ConnectToDB();
        $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C://stats/imports/All Members/ALL_MEMBERS_(ACTIVE)_30_09_2018.csv'
                INTO TABLE stats.members_test
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                ESCAPED BY '\\'  
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                (mem_no, @entered_on, @date_of_joining, mem_status, @mem_status_date, pitch_code, branch_code, section_code, sub_section_code, mem_sector, emp_status, employer, homeworker, workplace, personal_contract, pay_method, @date_paid_upto, home_country, work_country, equal_opps_consent, mem_ben_consent, priv_agree_consent, app_method, age, gender)
                SET date_of_joining = str_to_date(@date_of_joining,'%d-%b-%Y'), 
                entered_on = str_to_date(@entered_on,'%d-%b-%Y'), 
                mem_status_date = str_to_date(@mem_status_date,'%d-%b-%Y'), 
                date_paid_upto = str_to_date(@date_paid_upto,'%d-%b-%Y')";


        $db->exec($sql);

    }

    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        $myError =  $e->getMessage();
        return $myError;
    }
```

Issue resolved. Had to add extra escape characters  to ESCAPED BY and LINES TERMINATED BY. The above code now works.

Comment: Can you show us the php code?

Comment: The script needs to read `C:\stats\...`. Is that directory in the computer where PHP runs?

Comment: I've added the PHP code.

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález, the php code is located: C:\xampp\htdocs\stats.

Comment: The backslash char is the escape character in both SQL and PHP. So `echo "... ESCAPED BY '\\'   ..."` is certainly not what you want. Just inspect or print `$sql` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean but how do I write it in that case? Sorry if a dumb question.

Comment: You type backslash twice to get a literal backslash. If you want two, you need to type four.